# How can I set a keyboard shortcut to toggle on/off e.g. the trackpad?

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-settings, trackpad

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have currently disabled the trackpad of my laptop by turning it off in "System settings -> Mouse & Touchpad". Can I set a keyboard shortcut to toggle the trackpad on and off like the option in the system settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a small script that checks the current state under a shortcut key, and make it subsequently switch to the other state.

This works in a lot of situations, eg toggling the trackpad, toggling visibility of (many) indicator icons etc. (see EDIT, down in the post)

The script below does that:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

key = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled"

cmd1 = "/bin/bash", "-c", "gsettings get "+key
new_state = "false" if subprocess.check_output(cmd1).decode("utf-8").strip()  == "true" else "true"
cmd2 = "gsettings set "+key+" "+new_state
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd2])
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `toggle_touchpad.py`
2. Test-run it by running (in a terminal) the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/toggle_touchpad.py
   ```
3. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key combination: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/toggle_touchpad.py
   ```

Now the shortcut key should toggle the touchpad on/off

#### Explanation

The touchpad is enabled / disabled by the key:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled
```

To get the current state:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled
```

To set to `enabled`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

To set to `disabled`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

### Notes

#### 1. Using absolute paths in Custom keyboard shortcuts

Like in `.desktop` files, relative paths like `~` cannot be used in custom keyboard shortcuts. Also, just like in terminal commands, spaces need to be escaped:

*Instead of:*

```
python3 ~/Keyboard\ shortcuts/toggle_touchpad.py
```

*use:*

```
python3 /home/yourname/"Keyboard shortcuts"/toggle_touchpad.py
```

#### 2. Using the command(s) in 15.04

Due to a bug (it seems) the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

works fine, however the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

needs to run twice (!!) to *disable*  the touchpad...

#### 3. Bash version of the script

For those who prefer a `bash` version for some reason:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

key="org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled"
current=$(gsettings get $key)

if [ "$current" == "true" ]; then
  gsettings set $key false
else
  gsettings set $key true
fi
```

Save it as `toggle_touchpad.sh`, run it with the command

```
/bin/bash /path/to/toggle_touchpad.sh
```

---

### EDIT

The script(s) above can be used to toggle *any* setting, done by a `gsettings` command, of the type `boolean` (false/true). Simply change the line:

```
key = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled"
```

By the corresponding key.

#### An example:

If I change the line to:

```
key = "com.canonical.indicator.sound visible"
```

It toggles visibility of the sound indicator icon.

Comment: The script is working correctly but I cant seem to set a keyboard shortcut for it.. I want to set ctrl + shift for the shortcut, but the  custom shortcut created is remaining disabled. When I click on the shortcut row to enter the new keys as instructed, instead of the text 'new acceralator' appearing as for other shortcuts, the dialog box to enter the name and the command opens again.

Comment: @In78 custom shortcuts always run with one or two "main" keys, like Ctrl, Super, Shift, and one "sub" key, like a character a-z, a number, or a Numpad key. Ctrl+Shift is not a valid combination :)

Comment: @In78 I noticed you unaccepted the answer, is there a problem?

Comment: Yes,  I have entered the shift+ alt + A as the keyboard shortcut.. but when I press the keys no change is taking place.. though when I am running the script from the terminal, it is working fine

Comment: @In78 P.S. in custom shortcuts, always use *absolute paths*.

Comment: I am using this command 'python3 ~/Keyboard\ shortcuts/toggle_touchpad.py'

Comment: @In78 see my edited answer :)

Comment: For the [at least] Ubuntu 15.10 setting seem to be moved to schema `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` key `send-events` values `enabled`/`disabled`. And even more: besides enabled/disabled values it accepts `disabled-on-external-mouse`, which makes unneeded almost all touchpad switching tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/24256/toggle-the-touchpad-on-or-off

Put the command in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -q 'TouchpadOff.*1'; echo $?)
```

This command also works:

```
tp=$(synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{ print $3 }') && tp=$((tp==0)) && synclient TouchpadOff=$tp
```

Create a shortcut for the *path to the script*. (Make that executable first.)