# Setup Toggle Key-combination for Ctrl (similar to CapLock is to Shift)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

Is it possible to setup a key toggle to make it as if a certain key is now being held down?

Specifically, I would like to be able to do is press some short key combination (e.g. `Ctrl` twice in succession) to toggle `Ctrl` on then press another short key combination (same or different) to disable it.  Is something like this reasonable to setup?

I looked at Sticky Keys but this seems different.  This seems to make it so a key is held down until the next key is pressed, not until it is disabled.

One place this would be helpful would be for several repeated Emacs navigation shortcuts and kill/yank commands (both in Emacs and other tools that offer the same keyboard shortcuts, e.g. unix command line).

Comment: Hi stvn66, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure, I wasn't able to test it yet. Will this Ctrl similar to how CapsLock toggles Shift?

Comment: Wait, I get the feeling I misunderstood your question. Is your goal to *only* keep the Ctrl key pressed a few seconds?

Comment: That's when I intend to activate it but if it applied to other keys that's fine, I would just turn it off. I really want something equivalent to the CapsLock key for Ctrl, some combination of key presses that afterwards makes it as if Ctrl was being held down, until deactivating using another (or the same) key combination.

Comment: Ah, then the script should do what you describe. A more fancy solution would be to automatically set it to *sticky* when Emacs is in front. Would that be something you'd like to use?

Comment: I really wish there was a way to change CapsLock to be CtrlLock since I never really use CapsLock, would definitely use CtrlLock, and CapsLock is so conveniently placed. I realize keyboards are programmed to send certain commands and it's not just a matter of remapping b/c there IS no CtrlLock key.

Comment: I don't always want it on with Emacs, it would definitely screw up other commands. I would want to turn it on when going to use the navigation keys for example Ctrl-u, Ctrl-d, etc.

Comment: Then the answer should work, apart from the fact that you need to activate/deactivate it with at least one "main" key (Ctrl, Alt, Super) + one sub key (number or charachter)

Comment: stvn66 From here, I cannot see what is exactly going on, what are possibly conflicting issues on your system and why it seems to work only partially. The bash script and the python version do *exactly* the same thing, by *exactly* the same procedure: toggle sticky on/off, like in System Settings, but now directly via `gsettings` command. I will remove my answer for now.

Comment: I don't think you should remove your answer as it could help someone else.

Comment: For that purpose, I'd prefer broadening  this one http://askubuntu.com/a/639232/72216 for general use some day, rather than starting *this* answer starting with leading a "lonely live".